# how to show only processes *not* matching a filter?

Tags: filter, htop

I'm using `htop` to interactively monitor my processes.

However, sometimes a few processes get "in the way" and I would like to filter them out.

Unfortunately, it seems that htop's built in filter (e.g. <kbd>F4</kbd>) only allows me to define a *positive* filter (only matches will be shown), and not *negative* filters (all but matches are shown).

Finally, I haven't found any documentation about the actual syntax of the search-string (*regexes* don't seem to work).

Comment: AFAIK is not possible. Any good reason to not use top? You can do it easily with it.

Comment: FWIW htop filtering should gain regex filtering soon, there is a complete though still unmerged pull-request on GitHub. https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/pull/428

Comment: The project was moved to https://github.com/htop-dev/htop but the MR seems to me forgotten.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it's doable with `htop` but if using another `top` implementation is an option, with the `top` implementation in `procps` on Linux (generally the default implementation there), from within `top`, you can

1. enter `o` (or `O` for case sensitive matching)
2. enter `!COMMAND=notwanted` (or `!USER=unwanted`)

to filter out the processes whose name (or command line after pressing `c`) contains `notwanted` (or whose username contains `unwanted`). Enter `=` to remove all the filters.

You can filter on any of the fields you want, but only when they are displayed. For instance, to exclude kernel tasks, you can ask for the `CODE` column to be displayed (with `f`) and then filter on `CODE>0` (with `o`).

Note that the default interface of that `top` implementation may look cruder than that of `htop`, but it has actually quite a lot more features (and you can configure it with colour and extra information if need be).

Comment: Any way to pass these filters via command line?

Answer (score 4):

Do not know of a direct way with `htop`

However you might be able to use the negating abilities of `pgrep` and feed a pid list to `htop`

Something like

```
htop -p "$(pgrep -vfd, 'java|python')"
```

This has the obvious disadvantage of not accounting for processes that start after `htop` starts running

Comment: good idea, but what i really want to do is filter out "garbage" processes when I see them; so your solution is not really "interactive" in that sense...