# htop / top with specifying process name filter on the command line - at program startup?

Tags: top, htop

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm already aware that I can start `htop`, and then hit F4 for filter, then type or paste a process name search query (say, `gphoto2` for looking for `gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service`), and then htop filters the shown processes: if there is no such process, it shows nothing, if it starts later, `htop` shows it then.

Now, I would like to start `htop` with filtering already from the command line, say:

```
htop --filter="gphoto2"
```

... and get the exact same behavior as if hitting F4 and typing in the terminal UI. This would be useful if integrating the command into, say, a `tmux` session.

I browsed through `man htop`, but unfortunately I cannot see such command line/option. Closest I've seen is `-p`, which as noted in [how to show only processes *not* matching a filter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231804/how-to-show-only-processes-not-matching-a-filter) :

> Something like
>
> ```
> htop -p "$(pgrep -vfd, 'java|python')"
> ```
>
> This has the obvious disadvantage of not accounting for processes that start after htop starts running

So, is there a way to set up process name filtering on the command line at startup, such that it takes account for newly killed or spawned processes (as if hitting F4 in `htop`s terminal UI) - for `htop`, or `top`, or any other similar program?

Comment: A very useful feature indeed! Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Hmm, it's 2021-03-25, I'm running htop version 3.0.5 under Arch and `--filter test`, `-F test`, `--filter="test"` and `-F="test"` all work for me just fine. This is included in the man page:

```
COMMAND-LINE OPTIONS
[...]
       -F --filter=FILTER
              Filter processes by command
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in top, not htop that I'm aware of.

You want the `-p` flag. For example: `top -p $(pgrep -d',' -f "geany")`

This will launch top with only processes for geany shown.

[image: top filtered to geany processes]

Comment: 1) The `-p` _is_ available in Htop. 2) The question specifically asked that “it takes account for newly killed or spawned processes”, which your answer does not provide.

Comment: Better than nothing, though, since on my legacy system, this command works at least, and not with `htop`, only with `top`. If you cannot install a newer version of `htop`, this is already a good start.

Answer (score 2):

I went looking for this option, too, and it doesn't exist. I settled for (using your search-term):

```
\# ps -aux |grep "[0-9] gphoto2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commands do not work in older versions, and you likely have one. Perhaps, you are also trying to make your way through a legacy system like me. The accepted answer already puts it right, only older versions have the problem, proof by example:

```bsh
$ htop -v
htop 1.0.1 - (C) 2004-2011 Hisham Muhammad
Released under the GNU GPL.

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
$ htop --filter test
htop: unrecognized option '--filter'
$ htop --filter "test"
htop: unrecognized option '--filter'
$ htop -F test
htop: invalid option -- 'F'
$ htop -F "test"
htop: invalid option -- 'F'
```

And from the other answer+comment:

```bsh
$ htop -p $(pgrep -d',' -f "test")
htop: invalid option -- 'p'
$ top -p $(pgrep -d',' -f "test")
--works--
```